# Нейронная сеть Помогите понять

Tags: java, нейронные-сети

Целый день насиловал мозг пытаясь понять как работает Нейроновая сеть. 
Как я понял приходит данные придаем им вес и передаем в скрытые нейроны(поля) после же суммируем и передаем в активиционный Метод который выводит ответ. Каждый же раз когда пытаюсь написать простую сеть получается какая-то фигня. Вот например задачка. Меня пригласили на вечеринку. И есть три фактора основаясь на которых я делаю решения идти мне на вечеринку или нет. Первый это есть ли дождь или нет. Вторая будет ли еда или нет. Третье будут ли друзья или нет. Вот вопросы которые меня мучают: 
1) как вычислить правильно вес?

2) как обучить сеть по нужному pattern?

Я же попытался решить это и получилось нечто:

```
public class Project {


//    factors[0] = dozhd
//    factors[1] = yeda
//    factors[2] = friends

private static double[] wes = new double[3];
private static double[] factors = new double[3];
private static double[][] pattern =
{
    {
       0,1,1,1
    },
    {
       0,0,1,1
    },
    {
       1,0,0,0
    },
    {
        1,0,1,0
    },
    {
        0,0,0,0
    }
};

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    factors[0] = 1;
    factors[1] = 0;
    factors[2] = 1;

    wes[0] = 0.2;
    wes[1] = 0.3;
    wes[2] = 0.5;
    summirowaniya();
}

public static void summirowaniya(){
    double result = factors[0]*wes[0]+factors[1]*wes[1]+factors[2]*wes[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++){
        if(factors[0] == pattern[i][0] && factors[1] == pattern[i][1] && factors[2] == pattern[i][2]){
            double patSum = pattern[i][0] + pattern[i][1] + pattern[i][2];
            System.out.println(patSum/2);
            System.out.println(result);
            if(activationFunct(patSum/2+result) != pattern[i][3]){
                System.out.println(activationFunct(patSum/2-result));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(pattern[i][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static int activationFunct(double d){
    return d >= 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
}

}
```

как видете получились какие-то записи кодера с уклоннастеми на сада-маза. 
Не думаю что для опытного программиста будет сложно решить задачу выше так что если не сложно уделите минуту и помогите разобраться с этим всем

Comment: где у вас функция потери? где функция оптимизации (например метод градиентного спуска)? где функция обратного распростанения ошибки? В сети куча примеров реализации наивных алгоритмов нейронных сетей на разных языках программирования... Но для начала стоит разобраться с теорией

Comment: а с какой книги или откуда этот пример ?

Comment: @elik  это не пример и после того как я немного подучился понял что даже не нейронная сеть

Comment: @user8978194 а что это что есть нейро сеть не биологическая)куда идти куда направляться ?

Comment: @elik На Хабре есть хорошие статьи а если знаешь английский то хороший материал найдешь если поискать. Предупреждаю сразу это понять сразу невозможно. Уже неделю читаю разные статьи и все равно знание на минимуме могу сказать

Comment: @user8978194 . благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нейронные сети - это достаточно обширная тема, если хотите просто пользоваться то не стоит вникать в подробности, но если хочется хоть немного понять принцип действия то мге помогли разобраться эти статья и видео:

[Нейронная сеть, обратное растпространение ошибки](http://robocraft.ru/blog/algorithm/560.html)

[Видео. Нейронные сети](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZG0j0pNY-4&list=PLsQAG1V_t58AmRRhu-UUKvDSy-gY3Vmdh)

Также можете глянуть на мои поделки, не критикуйте если что, я тоже собирал информацию по крупицам:

[GitHub NeuralNetwork](https://github.com/arachnoden/NeuralNetwork/tree/master/src/neuralnetwork)

Comment: arachnoden а есть гдето пример работ с нейроновыми  сетям для . java ?

Comment: Из крупных - TensorFlow от Google, из мелких - целая куча на github, поиск в помощ, вот моя например.
https://github.com/arachnoden/LyricNN/tree/master/src/lyricnn

Comment: Анализирует текст, составляет свой текст на основе проанализированного, использует мою-же нейронную сеть.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Project {


//    factors[0] = dozhd
//    factors[1] = yeda
//    factors[2] = friends

private static double[] wes = new double[3];
private static double[] factors = new double[3];
// патерн т.е обучающий набор уже определили в main как factors
// и произвели правильное матричное умножение
// он более полный но вы использовали factors
private static double[][] pattern =
{
    {
       0,1,1,1
    },
    {
       0,0,1,1
    },
    {
       1,0,0,0
    },
    {
        1,0,1,0
    },
    {
        0,0,0,0
    }
};

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    factors[0] = 1;
    factors[1] = 0;
    factors[2] = 1;

    wes[0] = 0.2;
    wes[1] = 0.3;
    wes[2] = 0.5;
    summirowaniya();
}

public static void summirowaniya(){
  // матричное умножение -правильно (1,3)x(3,1)=(1,1)
    double result = factors[0]*wes[0]+factors[1]*wes[1]+factors[2]*wes[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++){
        if(factors[0] == pattern[i][0] && factors[1] == pattern[i][1] && factors[2] == pattern[i][2]){
            double patSum = pattern[i][0] + pattern[i][1] + pattern[i][2];
            System.out.println(patSum/2);
            System.out.println(result);
            if(activationFunct(patSum/2+result) != pattern[i][3]){
                System.out.println(activationFunct(patSum/2-result));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(pattern[i][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static int activationFunct(double d){ // функция активации - пороговая,правильно
    return d >= 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
}

}
```

Веса можно настроить,только проведя обратное распространение,здесь его нет,там нужно опять же матричное умножение и производная функции для получающихся векторов.